# Autocorrelation interpretation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Hi I am trying to understand how to interpret autocorrelation:
[image: a]

By looking at the graph how can we say the auto-correlation with the previous period (t + 1 in relation to t). TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The following section from the *Forecasting Principles and Practice* book may help you to understand the interpretation of the Auto-correlation plots.

Thanks.

[1] https://otexts.com/fpp2/autocorrelation.html